# Screenshot on Android Xamarin , Wide system screenshot

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, screenshot

My problem in short, I want to take a screenshot for the screen that the user see, not my Activity. Let's say my Application is minimized, the screenshot has be taken for the screen itself, not for my app.

I red somewhere that it's possible on non rooted devices since API 19 maybe or 4.0 android, But I couldn't find a way to do that.

I tried many solutions on the internet but nothing work. Red a lot but found nothing.

I found this code but, sure it takes a screenshot for my application ( layout )

Here is the OnCreate Method :

```
    ImageView img;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Button btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        img = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        btn.Click += Btn_Click;
    }

    public byte[] CaptureScreen()
    {
        var view = Window.DecorView.RootView;
        view.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
        Bitmap bitmap = view.GetDrawingCache(true);
        byte[] bitmapData;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
            bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
        }
        return bitmapData;
    }
```

To add it to an imageView when button click:

```
 private  void Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(CaptureScreen(), 0, CaptureScreen().Length);
        img.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

but As I said : it takes a screenshot for the layout, not the real screen.

I tried to hide or minimize the app, but nothing happened.

Comment: you can't take screenshot of anything except your own app. Just imagine - if you could, then you could have access to most part of private users' information.

Comment: Thank you for ur replay, would I ask how most apps can take a screenshot or recording video for ur game or something like that? There are a lot of apps I think do that, How could that happen ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. After searching a lot here and there, I discover that there is a new class from java will do the job for you. It's Media projection. It'll work on **Android Lollipop 5.0 or higher and doesn't need root**
and all apps in play store using it as I tried to download many apps to get the idea behind taking a screenshot.

Here is the documentation about it :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection